# web service reliablility with CXF - MQ

Tags: soa, activemq-classic, cxf, esb

How can I achieve reliability of web service in CXF ?

It is used in financial domain and involved in payment system, so requirement is that it must be 100% reliable and secure. for security I have added username/password authentication using ws-security (intercepter).

Do I need to use any Middleware (ActiveMQ) for transprot so that MQ provide reliability and security ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question; however, I assume your requirements for reliability *do not extend beyond the regular* **WS-*** *specifications*.

Apache CXF **does** conform to [WS-ReliableMessaging specification](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-reliablemessaging.html). Additionally, it also supports [WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html) and [WS-Addressing](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-addressing.html). I believe this should be enough for most reliability and security requirements.